# How do I stop Windows 8 from timing out after 1 minute and going to the login screen? (Lockscreen already disabled)

Tags: windows-8, screensaver

How do I stop Windows 8 from timing out after 1 minute and going to the login screen? (Lockscreen already disabled) This is very annoying when i'm trying to work. I have changed everything in power settings to 15 minutes but the screen still times out after 1 minute then goes to the Password / login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check your screen saver settings under personalization
`right click the desktop`(not metro).
  It is most likely set to 1 minute and you might want to uncheck the lock option as well.

Comment: Thanks Nels Larsen, but every time I change the time from 1 minute to 15 mins, hit <apply> then <ok> it seems to reset the timer back to 1 minute by itself...???

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/ace4085a-b0ba-4a98-898d-cd92d9e88e13

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Windows Logo key + R to launch a Run
2. Type regedit into the Run dialog and press Enter.
3. In the left pane of the Registry Editor, navigate to the following
   directory:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Power > PowerSettings > 238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20 > 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0
4. In the right pane of the Registry Editor, double-click on a value
   named Attributes to modify it.
5. Replace whatever is in this value’s Value data field with 2.
6. Click on OK.
7. Exit the Registry Editor.
8. Once you have applied the registry fix, you need to change your
   system unattended sleep timeout to a longer period of time. To do
   so, you need to:
9. Open the Start Menu.
10. Search for “power options”.
11. Click on the search result titled Power Options.
12. Click on Change plan settings under your selected power plan.
13. Click on Change advanced power settings.
14. Click on Change settings that are currently unavailable.
15. Click on Sleep.
16. Select System unattended sleep timeout. The value for this setting
    will probably be set to 2 minutes – change it to something longer,
    for example, 30 minutes.
17. Also, click on “Hibernate After” and then select a longer period of
    time such as 30 minutes.
18. System unattended sleep timeout apply your changes and save and exit.

I hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Win 8.1: You can solve this in the Screensaver settings control panel: Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Personalization -> Change screen Saver = Screen saver settings:
Adjacent to Wait Box is a small box: On resume, display logon screen. Click in the box to remove the check and you will not be returned to the Logon screen when you resume work. This problem has nothing to do with timings!